# Why do the friction forces in this simulation make objects behave in an unstable way?

Tags: c++, physics, game-physics

The following code for resolving collisions between two objects assumes a resitution of zero. The `inverse_inertia` of a body is represented as a matrix (`glm::mat4`).

```
void apply_impulse(Body& body, glm::vec3 impulse, glm::vec3 offset)
{
    body.velocity += impulse * body.inverse_mass;
    body.angular_velocity += body.inverse_inertia * glm::cross(offset, impulse);
}

void resolve_collision(Body& a, Body& b, glm::vec3 contact_point, glm::vec3 normal)
{
    glm::vec3 ra = contact_point - a.position;
    glm::vec3 rb = contact_point - b.position;

    glm::vec3 relative_velocity =
        b.velocity + glm::cross(b.angular_velocity, rb) -
        a.velocity - glm::cross(a.angular_velocity, ra);

    // Not moving towards each other, ignore the collision as it will be resolved anyway
    if (glm::dot(relative_velocity, normal) > 0) {
        return;
    }

    normal = glm::normalize(normal);

    float inverse_mass_sum = a.inverse_mass + b.inverse_mass +
        glm::length2(a.inverse_inertia * glm::cross(ra, normal)) +
        glm::length2(b.inverse_inertia * glm::cross(rb, normal));

    float normal_impulse = -glm::dot(relative_velocity, normal) / inverse_mass_sum;

    apply_impulse(a, -normal_impulse * normal, ra);
    apply_impulse(b, normal_impulse * normal, rb);

    // Recalculate after normal impulse
    relative_velocity =
        b.velocity + glm::cross(b.angular_velocity, rb) -
        a.velocity - glm::cross(a.angular_velocity, ra);
    glm::vec3 relative_momentum = relative_velocity / inverse_mass_sum;

    // Apply friction
    glm::vec3 friction_impulse;
    if (glm::length2(relative_momentum) < glm::length2(normal_impulse * static_friction)) {
        friction_impulse = -relative_momentum;
    }
    else {
        friction_impulse = -normal_impulse * glm::normalize(relative_momentum) * dynamic_friction;
    }
    apply_impulse(a, -friction_impulse, ra);
    apply_impulse(b, friction_impulse, rb);
}
```

When I run this code, it works fine on lower values like 1, 2 or 3 of `static_friction` and `dynamic_friction`, even though it looks like it slides a bit. But when I raise them both to, say, 9999, it overreacts instantly, flinging away the objects at extreme speeds. It shouldn't do that since the last `if` statement of `resolve_collision` should serve to "clamp" the friction impulse to on that makes the relative velocity exactly zero. But it doesn't seem to do that.

When setting the frictions to around 10-20, the linear and angular velocities of the ball seem to jiggle back and forth.

What am I doing wrong here? The section of the code that I think is most likely to be wrong is:

```
float inverse_mass_sum = a.inverse_mass + b.inverse_mass +
    glm::length2(a.inverse_inertia * glm::cross(ra, normal)) +
    glm::length2(b.inverse_inertia * glm::cross(rb, normal));
```

But I have no idea how this it is wrong. I want to add that I could do this with only one moving object:

```
for (auto& platform : platforms) {
    glm::vec3 contact_point;
    if (intersects(platform, ball, contact_point)) {
        // Only react if moving towards the platform
        if (glm::dot(ball.position - contact_point, ball.velocity) > 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // Collision with the platform applies a normal impulse
        glm::vec3 normal = glm::normalize(ball.position - contact_point);
        float normal_impulse = -ball.mass * glm::dot(normal, ball.velocity);
        ball.velocity += normal_impulse * normal;

        // Apply friction
        glm::vec3 relative_momentum = ball.mass * ball.velocity +
            inertia(ball) * glm::cross(ball.position - contact_point, ball.angular_velocity);
        apply_impulse(
            ball,
            friction_impulse(relative_momentum, normal_impulse),
            contact_point - ball.position);
    }
}
```

With `friction_impulse` being defined as:

```
glm::vec3 friction_impulse(glm::vec3 relative_momentum, float normal_impulse)
{
    if (glm::length2(relative_momentum) < glm::length2(normal_impulse * static_friction)) {
        return -relative_momentum;
    }
    else {
        return -normal_impulse * glm::normalize(relative_momentum) * dynamic_friction;
    }
}
```

Feel free to move this to gamedev or whatever fits best, I am not sure where to put it.

Comment: You haven't given us enough to reproduce the problem, but we can narrow it down. Is it the static or kinetic friction case that causes the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calculating your inverse mass correctly (I think, passing glance) for your normal resolution. However you need to calculate a *different* inverse mass sum for your friction resolution.

When calculating terms for friction you swap all instances of the `normal` for the `tangent` vector.

```
Vec3 raCrossT = Cross( ra, tangent );
Vec3 rbCrossT = Cross( rb, tangent );
real inverseMass = a.inverse_mass + b.inverse_mass;
inverseMass += Dot( raCrossT, a.inverse_inertia * raCrossT );
inverseMass += Dot( rbCrossT, b.inverse_inertia * rbCrossT );
```

You will then calculate a new impulse scalar specifically for the friction impulse.

Basically you are mixing calculations between completely isolated impulses. I see you recomputed relative velocity, which is good! You should also compute a separate inverse mass sum, as the inverse mass sum seen by the friction constraint is going to be different.

To solve for a tangent vector you can use relative velocity and the contact normal, and find the velocity along the tangent vector during the collision:

```
Vec3 tangentVelocity = vRel - normal * Dot( vRel, normal );
Vec3 tangent = tangentVelocity.Normalized( );
```

Luckily Glenn recently posted some of his 3D friction and contact resolution code for you to examine: http://gafferongames.com/virtualgo/collision-response-and-coulomb-friction/

Answer (score 2):

```
float inverse_mass_sum = a.inverse_mass + b.inverse_mass + ...
...
float normal_impulse = -glm::dot(relative_velocity, normal) / inverse_mass_sum;
```

Note that `1 / (1/a + 1/b)` is NOT equal to `1 / (a+b)`

Please could you explain what exactly your vector `normal` is?

Comment: `normal` is the normal vector of the surface on `b` that `a` hit. So what I really want to use is `1 / (1 / a.inverse_mass + 1 / b.inverse_mass`? How do I extend this notion onto the rotational inertia?

Comment: Wait a minute... `1 / (1 / a.inverse_mass + 1 / b.inverse_mass` unfortunately won't work since any of them can be zero.

Comment: A zero inverse mass means infinite mass (in the model you use, not generally). Your model seems a bit odd, wouldn't it be easier to use forces instead of impulses?

Comment: If I used forces, it would be a lot more difficult to make it so that, given a large enough friction coefficient, the surfaces would kind of stick together perfectly.